# Determine if the current user has write permission in a directory

Tags: shell, permissions

I know you can determine the owner of directory by doing:

```
ls -ld ~/foo | awk '{ print $3 }'
```

You could then compare it to the current user by doing this:

```
if [[ $(ls -ld ~/foo | awk '{ print $3 }') == "$USER" ]] # or $(id -u -n ) instead of $USER
then
    echo "You are the owner"
else
    echo "You are NOT the owner"
fi
```

But you can have permissions to write without being the owner. How do you determine this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I suppose

```
if [ -w ~/foo ]; then ....
```

should do what you want.

Also, `stat -c %U ~/foo` is a better way to obtain the owner than parsing `ls` output.

Comment: Note that `stat` is specific to modern Linux systems, other unices may have a different `stat` or none at all. [Parsing ls is usually recipe for trouble](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), but parsing the owner as the third word mostly works (things break down afterwards); it's still not perfect (some systems allow spaces in user names).